# What is the difference between defining your template inside Vue options vs outside?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue, if someone could clarify the difference between declaring a template like this:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
    template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
})
```

vs

```
<template>
    <div>A custom component!</div>
</template>
```

and it's advantages, that would be wonderful! I'm trying to create a lightweight application and I'm not sure which one is more appropriate. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no functional difference. It is a matter of what convention you want to use and how your builder likes to build things. In a non-development environment, your templates *should* be [pre-compiled into render functions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html#Pre-Compiling-Templates).

Comment: Oh I guess I misunderstood the docs. I'm mainly concerned with production builds.. So for production builds, I should define templates in a component and compile with webpack?

Comment: Yes, that is how webpack likes to build things.

Comment: Huh I wonder if it truly effects the size of the end build. Thank you for your help friend!

Answer (score 1):

Both implementations work the same. The later one is using [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), which might be more readable, but both ways are proper.